# Is modelmapper designed to use in android?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, modelmapper

I am using retrofit with GSON and I would like to create another layer of object abstraction and Modelmapper seems to be a right fit for my usecase.

Can I use modelmapper in android. Are there any performance caveats which I must be aware of ?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, ModelMapper doesn't really play nicely with Android. The main reason is it's [Property Mapping API](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/) relies on being able to read bytecode from PropertyMap classes, and since Android's bytecode format is different, it's currently not supported.

That said, ModelMapper will run on Android to some extent (I haven't tried it), but the Property Mapping API likely won't work.